# where condition for date & time is not working

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

i want to execute this query,

SELECT uuid,data,name,time,tracker,type,userid FROM standardevents0805 
where time > '2014/08/04 00:00:00'; 
(i tried by putting in double quotes also "2014/08/04 00:00:00")

but it is not working properly.

below is the description of my column-family,

```
CREATE TABLE standardevents0805 (
  uuid timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
  data text,
  name text,
  time timestamp,
  tracker text,
  type text,
  userid text
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};

CREATE INDEX time_in ON standardevents0805 (time);

CREATE INDEX userid_in ON standardevents0805 (userid);
```

Comment: you want to use timeuuid instead of a timestamp, [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/jericevans/cassandra-by-example-data-modelling-with-cql3) give a solid overview of how to build a timeline.

Comment: in my previous table datatype of time was varchar so in new table i am creating table as a timeuuid and trying to copy the data it is not allowing and it will not allow that is but obvious. 
So apart from timeuuid we can not perform conditions in time?

Answer (score 2):

You've put a lookup index on time, but such indexes (at the time of writing) allow only equals operations. Range queries can be performed only on clustering keys.

Comment: the same way even if i am giving query like
select count(*) from standardevents0805 where time='2014/08/04 00:00:00' limit 100;('2014/08/04') 

it is giving me error like  unable to coerce '2014/08/04 00:00:00' to a  formatted date (long).

i will execute with clustering keys for sure..

Comment: if i am seeing the normal output by select * from tablename then it is giving me time field in the above format only.